# How do I unzip many files to new respective folders? [Win 10]

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, batch, zip

Given multiple zip files in a folder named 1.zip, 2.zip, ... how do I quickly unzip them all to folder '1', folder '2', ... in Windows 10 Pro?

I am using a Surface Pro 4, though I also have a Windows 10 desktop available.

Of course I can manually unzip each file with a mouse, but I wish to use the computer more efficiently. I have almost no experience using the command prompt or supershell but I am eager to learn. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any special requirements install a compatible compressed archive manager of your choice (7Z, WinZip, WinRar etc.) and most of them (at least 7z and WinRar) will have the option to extract each archive to a separate folder.

From a command prompt it's still going to be the easiest to use one of those utilities that has a command prompt interface (e.g. `unrar`). Likely you will be able to replace the file selection with something like `*.zip`.

See also: [How to unzip a file using the command line? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021557/how-to-unzip-a-file-using-the-command-line)

Comment: Just tried WinZip Universal from the Windows 10 app store and it did not work, instead wrongly giving an error message that the file was corrupt (presumably encountering the same 'long filename' problem the Windows 10 built-in extractor cannot manage).